# Solr 4.10.3 is not proceeding to leader election on new cluster startup - hangs with nodes down

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I've recently upgraded one of our services from 4.10.1 to 4.10.3 and noticed that, when starting a new cluster, all nodes stay in the 'down' state. Looking at the logs and comparing them to my previous version I also note that the cluster never advances to leader election.

**Background:**
We use a fairly simple start procedure using start.jar, and rely on auto core discovery. We have 3 zookeeper instances running on other hosts, and have started either 1 or 2 Solr instances on separate hosts for testing the new version. All configuration files contained in the ZK instances are up to date with solr 4.10.3 standards. Solr home is the default (/solr). There is no difference between our 4.10.1 and 4.10.3 deploys save the solr-match-version in solrconfig.xml. All other configuration changes between the versions aren't present.

**core.properties:**
These settings are unnecessary because everything matches up with our directory structure, but here it is anyway. The given property is specified on the command line as ttPoiMDS (which you'll note below in the logs).

```
name ${our.index.name:}
collection ${our.index.name:}
```

**Solr log:**
Below is the output to our logs.

```
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 56 028 jetty-8.1.10.v20130312
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 56 060 Opened /logs/access_log
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 56 069 Deployment monitor /install_dir/solr-4.10.3/contexts at interval 0
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 56 079 Deployable added: /install_dir/solr-4.10.3/contexts/solr-jetty-context.xml
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 57 710 NO JSP Support for /solr, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 57 987 SolrDispatchFilter.init()
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 006 JNDI not configured for solr (NoInitialContextEx)
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 007 solr home defaulted to 'solr/' (could not find system property or JNDI)
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 007 new SolrResourceLoader for directory: 'solr/'
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 232 Loading container configuration from /install_dir/solr-4.10.3/solr/solr.xml
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 363 Config-defined core root directory: /install_dir/solr-4.10.3/solr
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 371 New CoreContainer 971279180
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 371 Loading cores into CoreContainer [instanceDir=solr/]
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 396 Setting socketTimeout to: 0
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 396 Setting urlScheme to: null
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 403 Setting connTimeout to: 0
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 403 Setting maxConnectionsPerHost to: 20
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 403 Setting corePoolSize to: 0
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 403 Setting maximumPoolSize to: 2147483647
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 403 Setting maxThreadIdleTime to: 5
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 403 Setting sizeOfQueue to: -1
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 403 Setting fairnessPolicy to: false
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 563 Creating UpdateShardHandler HTTP client with params: socketTimeout=0&connTimeout=0&retry=false
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 565 SLF4J impl is org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 566 Registering Log Listener [Log4j (org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory)]
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 568 Host Name: 
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 568 Zookeeper client=our_zk_instance:<port_num>,...
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 625 Waiting for client to connect to ZooKeeper
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 663 Watcher org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager@76cdaff7 name:ZooKeeperConnection Watcher:our_zk_instance:<port_num> got event WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null path:null type:None
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 663 Client is connected to ZooKeeper
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 726 Register node as live in ZooKeeper:/live_nodes/<our_ip>:8983_solr
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 732 makePath: /live_nodes/<our_ip>:8983_solr
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 748 Overseer (id=null) closing
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 763 I am going to be the leader <our_ip>:8983_solr
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 767 makePath: /overseer_elect/leader
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 778 Overseer (id=93155855038349317-<our_ip>:8983_solr-n_0000000002) starting
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 869 Starting OverseerAutoReplicaFailoverThread autoReplicaFailoverWorkLoopDelay=10000 autoReplicaFailoverWaitAfterExpiration=30000 autoReplicaFailoverBadNodeExpiration=60000
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 901 Process current queue of collection creations
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 905 Updating cluster state from ZooKeeper... 
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 937 Starting to work on the main queue
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 975 Looking for core definitions underneath /install_dir/solr-4.10.3/solr
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 989 Found core ttPoiMDS in /install_dir/solr-4.10.3/solr/ttPoiMDS/
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 989 Found 1 core definitions
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 995 publishing core=ttPoiMDS state=down collection=ttPoiMDS
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 58 995 numShards not found on descriptor - reading it from system property
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 59 002 look for our core node name
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 59 002 waiting to find shard id in clusterstate for ttPoiMDS
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 59 002 Check for collection zkNode:ttPoiMDS
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 59 003 LatchChildWatcher fired on path: /overseer/queue state: SyncConnected type NodeChildrenChanged
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 59 004 Collection zkNode exists
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 59 004 Load collection config from:/collections/ttPoiMDS
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 59 008 path=/collections/ttPoiMDS configName=ttPoiMDS specified config exists in ZooKeeper
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 59 008 new SolrResourceLoader for directory: '/install_dir/solr-4.10.3/solr/ttPoiMDS/'
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 59 013 Update state numShards=1 message={
    "operation":"state",
    "numShards":"1",
    "shard":null,
    "roles":null,
    "state":"down",
    "core":"ttPoiMDS",
    "collection":"ttPoiMDS",
    "node_name":"<our_ip>:8983_solr",
    "base_url":"http://<our_ip>:8983/solr"}
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 59 013 node=core_node2 is already registered
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 59 013 shard=shard1 is already registered
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 59 042 A cluster state change: WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:NodeDataChanged path:/clusterstate.json, has occurred - updating... (live nodes size: 1)
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 59 079 Adding specified lib dirs to ClassLoader
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 59 080 Adding 'file:/install_dir/solr-4.10.3/lib/mq/solr-search-ahead-2.0.0.jar' to classloader
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 59 236 Using Lucene MatchVersion: 4.10.3
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 59 400 Loaded SolrConfig: solrconfig.xml
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 59 412 Reading Solr Schema from /configs/ttPoiMDS/schema.xml
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 59 451 [ttPoiMDS] Schema name=poiMDS
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 59 841 user.dir=/install_dir/solr-4.10.3
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 59 841 SolrDispatchFilter.init() done
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 59 870 Deployable added: /install_dir/solr-4.10.3/contexts/ns-jetty-context.xml
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 59 943 NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
INFO 2015-01-17 16 39 59 997 Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8983
```

If I've managed to miss something please let me know. This is what I suspect as it would be hard to believe that something has slipped into the codebase. It does look like the ZkController class has been changed significantly though.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT**

I have tried using the *example* deploy included in the distribution package, using an external ZooKeeper host and automatic core discovery, and have experienced the same issue.

Comment: After submitting this to the Solr mailing list, Hoss gave me some pointers that helped set me straight. In all honesty, my configuration has a missing link, something to another file, that was once failing quietly but now is failing-and-stopping quietly. A JIRA already exists for this condition so I expect it will be ironed out in 4.10.4. Cheers!